# Cannot retrieve field from a JSON object return by amazon-product-api

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, amazon-product-api

Hello every body I am new node.js I have this code `

```
client.itemSearch({
  keywords:'borderlands 2' ,

  searchIndex: 'VideoGames',

  responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Images'
}).then(function(results){
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results[0].ItemAttributes));
    var kson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0].ItemAttributes));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(kson['Title']));

}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});`
```

The json result of the amazon search is this `[{"Binding":["Video Game"],"Brand":["2K"],"CatalogNumberList":[{"CatalogNumberListElement":["49101"]}],"Creator":[{"_":"Take 2","$":{"Role":"Creator"}}],"Department":["Video Games"],"EAN":["0163120331895"],"EANList":[{"EANListElement":["0163120331895","0151903126141","0031111574449","0088021472273","0021113169989","0100177413464","7104254910160","0710425491016","0745449851300"]}],"Edition":["Standard"],"ESRBAgeRating":["Mature"],"Feature":["Dynamic Co-op online, split-screen and LAN: Share your adventures with friends both online and via LAN. Borderlands 2 features a seamless system enabling you to drop in and drop out of a campaign without ever having to restart the game.","World Connected Story: You will find yourself left for dead in the frozen tundra of Pandora as you begin your quest of revenge and redemption.","New Badass Gun System: An entirely new take on the groundbreaking procedural system means millions upon millions of possible weapons. The variety and style of guns in Borderlands 2 is staggering.","87 Bazillion Everything: In addition to the new gun system, you will lust after procedurally generated shields, grenades, Alien Artifacts, class mods and much, much more. And you thought the original Borderlands had a ton of loot!","Brand new environments on Pandora: Hunt through entirely brand new areas of Pandora that are more alive than ever!","Choose from all new characters and classes including the Gunzerker, who can dual-wield any two weapons in the game","Share your adventures with friends both online and via LAN with a seamless co-op system enabling you to drop in and drop out of a campaign without ever having to restart the game","Improved story integration which finds you left for dead in the frozen tundra of Pandora as you begin your quest of revenge and redemption","An entirely new take on the groundbreaking procedural system means millions upon millions of possible weapons","In addition to the new gun system, players lust after procedurally generated shields, grenades, alien artifacts, class mods and much, much more"],"Genre":["shooter-action-game-genre"],"HardwarePlatform":["Xbox 360"],"IsAdultProduct":["0"],"IsAutographed":["0"],"IsEligibleForTradeIn":["1"],"IsMemorabilia":["0"],"ItemDimensions":[{"Height":[{"_":"752","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}],"Length":[{"_":"531","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}],"Weight":[{"_":"19","$":{"Units":"hundredths-pounds"}}],"Width":[{"_":"51","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}]}],"ItemPartNumber":["710425491016"],"Label":["2K"],"Languages":[{"Language":[{"Name":["English"],"Type":["Published"]},{"Name":["English"],"Type":["Original Language"]},{"Name":["English"],"Type":["Unknown"]}]}],"ListPrice":[{"Amount":["1999"],"CurrencyCode":["USD"],"FormattedPrice":["$19.99"]}],"Manufacturer":["2K"],"ManufacturerMinimumAge":[{"_":"96","$":{"Units":"months"}}],"Model":["49101"],"MPN":["49101"],"NumberOfItems":["1"],"OperatingSystem":["Xbox 360"],"PackageDimensions":[{"Height":[{"_":"50","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}],"Length":[{"_":"750","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}],"Weight":[{"_":"20","$":{"Units":"hundredths-pounds"}}],"Width":[{"_":"530","$":{"Units":"hundredths-inches"}}]}],"PackageQuantity":["1"],"PartNumber":["49101"],"Platform":["Xbox 360"],"ProductGroup":["Video Games"],"ProductTypeName":["CONSOLE_VIDEO_GAMES"],"PublicationDate":["2012-09-18"],"Publisher":["2K"],"RegionCode":["36222"],"ReleaseDate":["2012-09-18"],"Studio":["2K"],"Title":["Borderlands 2 - Xbox 360"],"TradeInValue":[{"Amount":["86"],"CurrencyCode":["USD"],"FormattedPrice":["$0.86"]}],"UPC":["021113169989"],"UPCList":[{"UPCListElement":["021113169989","100177413464","031111574449","163120331895","088021472273","745449851300","151903126141","710425491016"]}]}]`

I can not find a way to retrieve the field title from the results!

Comment: any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.itemSearch({
    keywords:'borderlands 2' ,
    searchIndex: 'VideoGames',
    responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Images'
}, function(err, results, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
         var amazon_product = JSON.parse(results[0].ItemAttributes);
         console.log(amazon_product.Title);
    }
});
```

I hope it helps :)